# How can I unsubscribe from this subscription?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, observable, angular-route-guards

I have a `PolicyGuard` with a method `canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)`.

In `canActivate` I create an observable, and inside of this observable I subscribe to an Observable that I retrieve from my `AbilityService`.

The observable I retrieve from `AbilityService` listens for changes to a users "policies"/"abilities".

This gets pretty messy when I am making changes to a user's "policies" and pushing those changes to the client using `Socket.io` as page re-direction to the home page can happen when I don't want it to (One subscription runs `obs.next(true)` while another subscription routes to home and runs `obs.next(false)`)

Is there a way I can make the subscription unsubscribe when leaving the page that the subscription was meant for?

```
@Injectable()
export class PolicyGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(protected router: Router, private abilityService: AbilityService) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        console.log("PolicyGuard() - canActivate()");

        return new Observable<boolean>(obs => {
            const observable = this.abilityService.getAbility();
            observable.subscribe(ability => {
                const can = ability.can(route.data.action, route.data.subject);

                if (can) {
                    obs.next(true);
                }
                else {
                    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
                    obs.next(false);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try rxjs take(1) with pipe before subscribe. It will take one emission and unsubscribe

Comment: I tried that. The problem with that is, if you're on a page in the application that you no longer have access to (due to the users policies being updated) then the page doesn't kick you back to home. I was thinking about using something like takeUntil() or takeWhile() somehow, but not sure what to use as a condition.

Answer (score 0):

You have currently created an additional Observable which is in my opinion not required. You could simply return `this.abilityService.getAbility()` and transform the return value with the RxJS `map` operator. This way Angular would take over and handle the subscription from your Observable.

This would look like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  console.log("PolicyGuard() - canActivate()");

  return this.abilityService.getAbility().pipe(
    map(ability => {
      const can = ability.can(route.data.action, route.data.subject);
     
      if (!can) {
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      }
      return can;
    });
  );
}
```

The example for canActivate on [angular.io](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate#description) does something simliar, just without the `map` operator.

Comment: With this solution I experience the same issue as using `take(1)` where if a user is on a page they no longer have access to (due to user policy/ability being updated) the user is not routed back to the home page. So I guess, somehow I could just make the `canActivate()` method fire again after user rules get updated without refreshing the page.

Comment: Do you mean with not kicked home, that the policy changes but the user is not directly navigated to home?

Comment: Yes because the subscription has ended after it runs once, and the route guard doesn't get called again when a user's rules update via Socket.io. Is there a way to trigger the `canActivate()` method to run again without refreshing the page?